# Git log filtering by folder case insensitive (Windows)

Tags: windows, git

I got the following command:

```
git log --oneline -- SQL\
```

That will return the commits with files of this SQL path.

But if I change a case, like this:

```
git log --oneline -- sQL\
```

It doesn't work. I can't find an option to make this command case insensitive. Is this possible?

Comment: According your specific example you can replace `sQL` with `[sS]QL`. But there is no solution with only git function.

Comment: Thank you, it's a good point and a effective workaround for my scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According your specific example you can replace `sQL` with `[sS]QL`. The `path` accepts simple regular expression.

```
git log --oneline -- [sS]QL\
```

There is no solution using git core function.